Vmware : new machine with existing suspended state
OS : Windows 11
In vmware workstation(v 17),
I've created a virtual machine,
and after numerous works and events,
finally arrived at a certain suspended state, denoted by S.
Now, I want to create a new machine (in a new folder), with the state S.
In detail :

I need only state S, nothing else.
All unnecessary things must be removed.
All necessary things must be simplified and gathered into one if possible.
Everything should work only with the contents of the new folder. (independency)

So what I can do is consolidating vmdk files :
Merging of VMDK files to Single VMDK - Diskname or some other argument is missing
That is, for only disk(.vmdk), I achived my goal.
But only with .vmdk files,
we can't make it into a virtual machines with the state S.
Hardware settings and RAM must be completely the same as those of S.
We need corresponding .vmx file, .vmem file, etc.
How can I do it?
@Ramhound :
At first, we cannot create a clone for a snapshot of a suspended state :


Create a snapshot. Then clone the snapshot into a new VM. You won't have the exact same files for obvious reasons.

@Ramhound : We cannot make a clone for a snapshot, if the snapshot is suspended. And.. whether being able to create a clone solves the problem is another question.

You answered your own question in that case. If you cannot create a snapshot then you cannot create a new VM based off that snapshot.

@Ramhound : There seems to be a misunderstanding. I can create a snapshot, but the clone feature is not for  snapshot of suspended state.

I just confirmed that I accidentally wrote a word wrong in the main text. I'm blaming myself. The text has now been corrected.

Just copy the VM directory.  Creating a clone does additional work to ensure that the copy will get a new MAC address and won't conflict with the original, but if you want an exact copy, just create an exact copy.  If you don't want a MAC address conflict, then you will need to power the VM off first since the MAC address can't be changed while the VM is powered-on or suspended.

@jamesdlin : Thank you, but first, I don't care about MAC address conflict issue. I mean, for me it doesn't matter if there is a Mac address conflict.

@jamesdlin Just copy VM directory? - yes it will work, but it does not meet the condition 2) I laid out in the main text. There can be many, nasty snapshots up to S. (Or there may be snapshots that extend in other branches.) What I want is only S, so any snapshots must be removed. So just copying VM directory is not what I want.

@imidak So make a copy of your VM first, get it into the state you want by deleting snapshots, etc., and then by making copies of that modified copy.

As explained in the comments, if you want a copy of a virtual machine in its exact state (including its UUID and MAC address), then just copy the VM directory.  The only real difference with copying the VM directory and making a full clone is that the full clone will get its UUID and MAC address reset to avoid conflicts with the original VM.
If there's any state that you don't want to be in the copy (such as snapshots), then delete those first.  If you don't want to modify the original, then copy the VM, modify the copy, and then make further copies of that copy.
Be aware that copies of suspended VMs might not be portable across hosts.  For example, you might have problems if you resume a copy on a host with different CPU features than the host it was suspended on.
